# Converting data from Json to String in python

Tags: python, json

Could anybody please explain how to convert the  following json data into a string in python. It's very big but i need your help... 
You can see it from the following link:-                                                    http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=delhi&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&appid=146f5f89c18a703450d3bd6737d4fc94
Please suggest it's solution it is important for my project :-)

Comment: json is already a string ...

Comment: The `json` module contains methods for `dumps` and `loads` which perform serialization back and forth from native objects (dicts, lists, etc) to a string for transmission to other languages.

Comment: Best to show what you've tried already, and explain what your goal with it is.  There may be better solutions than doing it the way you're thinking of, and context helps people think about it.

Answer (score 0):

You can decode a JSON string in python like this:

```
import json
data = json.loads('json_string')
```

Source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?q=delhi&mode=json&units=metric&cnt=7&appid=146f5f89c18a703450d3bd6737d4fc94'

response = requests.get(url)

response.text # this is a string
response.json() # this is a json dictionary

s = "The City is {city[name]} todays HIGH is {list[0][temp][max]}".format(**response.json())
print s
```

Answer (score 0):

Some simple code that will read the JSON from your page and produce a Python dictionary follows. I have used the implicit concatenation of adjacent strings to improve the layout of the code.

```
import json
import urllib.request
f = urllib.request.urlopen
      (url="http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily?"
           "q=delhi&mode=json&units=metric&"
           "cnt=7&appid=146f5f89c18a703450d3bd6737d4fc94")
content = f.read()
result = json.loads(content.decode("utf-8"))
print(result)
```

This gives me the following output (which I have not shown in code style as it would appear in a single long line):

{'city': {'coord': {'lat': 28.666668, 'lon': 77.216667}, 'country': 'IN', 'id': 1273294, 'population': 0, 'name': 'Delhi'}, 'cnt': 7, 'message': 0.0081, 'list': [{'dt': 1467093600, 'weather': [{'icon': '01n', 'id': 800, 'description': 'clear sky', 'main': 'Clear'}], 'humidity': 82, 'clouds': 0, 'pressure': 987.37, 'speed': 2.63, 'temp': {'max': 32, 'eve': 32, 'night': 30.67, 'min': 30.67, 'day': 32, 'morn': 32}, 'deg': 104}, {'dt': 1467180000, 'weather': [{'icon': '10d', 'id': 501, 'description': 'moderate rain', 'main': 'Rain'}], 'humidity': 74, 'clouds': 12, 'pressure': 989.2, 'speed': 4.17, 'rain': 9.91, 'temp': {'max': 36.62, 'eve': 36.03, 'night': 31.08, 'min': 29.39, 'day': 35.61, 'morn': 29.39}, 'deg': 126}, {'dt': 1467266400, 'weather': [{'icon': '02d', 'id': 801, 'description': 'few clouds', 'main': 'Clouds'}], 'humidity': 71, 'clouds': 12, 'pressure': 986.56, 'speed': 3.91, 'temp': {'max': 36.27, 'eve': 35.19, 'night': 30.87, 'min': 29.04, 'day': 35.46, 'morn': 29.04}, 'deg': 109}, {'dt': 1467352800, 'weather': [{'icon': '10d', 'id': 502, 'description': 'heavy intensity rain', 'main': 'Rain'}], 'humidity': 100, 'clouds': 48, 'pressure': 984.48, 'speed': 0, 'rain': 18.47, 'temp': {'max': 30.87, 'eve': 30.87, 'night': 28.24, 'min': 24.96, 'day': 27.16, 'morn': 24.96}, 'deg': 0}, {'dt': 1467439200, 'weather': [{'icon': '10d', 'id': 501, 'description': 'moderate rain', 'main': 'Rain'}], 'humidity': 0, 'clouds': 17, 'pressure': 983.1, 'speed': 6.54, 'rain': 5.31, 'temp': {'max': 35.48, 'eve': 32.96, 'night': 27.82, 'min': 27.82, 'day': 35.48, 'morn': 29.83}, 'deg': 121}, {'dt': 1467525600, 'weather': [{'icon': '10d', 'id': 501, 'description': 'moderate rain', 'main': 'Rain'}], 'humidity': 0, 'clouds': 19, 'pressure': 984.27, 'speed': 3.17, 'rain': 7.54, 'temp': {'max': 34.11, 'eve': 34.11, 'night': 27.88, 'min': 27.53, 'day': 33.77, 'morn': 27.53}, 'deg': 133}, {'dt': 1467612000, 'weather': [{'icon': '10d', 'id': 503, 'description': 'very heavy rain', 'main': 'Rain'}], 'humidity': 0, 'clouds': 60, 'pressure': 984.82, 'speed': 5.28, 'rain': 54.7, 'temp': {'max': 33.12, 'eve': 33.12, 'night': 26.15, 'min': 25.78, 'day': 31.91, 'morn': 25.78}, 'deg': 88}], 'cod': '200'}

Comment: A pleasure. Since it appeared to assist you, you might want to consider marking it accepted, or upvoting it